# How to get member list based on role by using buddypress?

Tags: plugins, php, buddypress

I am new in buddypress.

My problem is: I have create a template for get member list based on role Like:

```
<?php if ( bp_has_members( bp_ajax_querystring( 'members' ). '&per_page=25&role=author' ) ) : ?>

    <ul id="members-list" class="item-list row kleo-isotope masonry">

      <?php while ( bp_members() ) : bp_the_member(); ?>
         <li><a href="<?php bp_member_permalink(); ?>"><?php bp_member_avatar(); ?></a></li>
      <?php endwhile; ?>

    </ul>
```

But i am not getting user list based on role. Please help me and suggest me any idea.

Answer (score 3):

To preserve pagination, try:

```
<?php    
$authors = get_users( array( 'fields' => 'ID', 'role' => 'author' ) );
$authors = implode(',', $authors);
?>

<?php if ( bp_has_members( bp_ajax_querystring( 'members' ). '&per_page=25&include=' . $authors) ) : ?>
//etc
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use this code directly below `while ( bp_members() ) : bp_the_member();` in the members loop, you’ll be able to see which members are author.

```
<?php 
   $user_id = bp_get_member_user_id(); 
   $user = new WP_User( $user_id );

   if ( $user->roles[0] == 'author' ) {
      echo 'this user is an author';
   } 
?>
```

I know this isn’t exactly what you’d like to do but it should put you on the right track.

Note: This code assumes that all of your users have a single role assigned.

Comment: But this will create problem in paging. because paging is depend on how much user coming using query . By using your code i can skip only other user inside loop

Comment: Create your custom function which help you to find this. Put the function get_custom_member() in your-theme/functions.php or in bp-custom.php. Why? So you can avoid using the $wpdb global in your template and the function will be available anywhere you have a member loop.

Comment: OR pass user_id into bp_has_members(). $user_role = array (
'role' => 'author',
);

$all_authors = get_users ($user_role);

$members_to_be_included = array ();
foreach ($all_authors as $all_author) {
$members_to_be_included[] = $all_author->ID;
}